# Docusaurus build missing fonts

Tags: reactjs, docusaurus

I load the custom font with the location in the `static/fonts` folder, it works fine when in development mode (`docusaurus start`), but when I build (`docusaurus build`), the results show that the fonts I used are not loading, because the `fonts` folder is outside the `static` folder.

[Folder structure when build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ToJX.png)

This is the snippet I made in the `custom.css` file

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Indonesiana';
    src: url('/static/fonts/Indonesiana.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/static/fonts/Indonesiana.svg#Indonesiana') format('svg'),
    url('/static/fonts/Indonesiana.eot'),
    url('/static/fonts/Indonesiana.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use relative paths and you will have a proper links upon build (assuming your css is in src/css):

```
 @font-face {
        font-family: 'Indonesiana';
        src: url('../../static/fonts/Indonesiana.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../../static/fonts/Indonesiana.svg#Indonesiana') format('svg'),
        url('../../static/fonts/Indonesiana.eot'),
        url('../../static/fonts/Indonesiana.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also add a font like this:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Indonesiana";
  src: url('/static/fonts/Indonesiana.woff') format('woff');
}
```

```css
:root {
  --ifm-font-family-base: "Indonesiana"
}
```

There are other ways to do it for different modes, such as:

```css
  --ifm-font-family-monospace: "Indonesiana";
```