# Docusaurus not loading custom fonts

Tags: reactjs, docusaurus

My problem is that Docusaurus it is not loading custom fonts. I have the following structure:

```
website
│      
└───src
│   │   pages
│   │   ...
│   │
│   └───css
│       │  custom.css
│   
└───static
    │       
    └─── fonts
           │       
           └─── Poppins
                  │  Poppins-Regular.ttf
                  │  Poppins-Bold.ttf
```

I have the fonts inside ../static/fonts/Poppins/ folder and inside my css/custom.css i have the following code:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins-Regular';
  src: url('../../static/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins-Bold';
  src: url('../../static/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
}

:root {
  --ifm-color-primary: #2e32ae;
  --ifm-font-family-base: 'Poppins-Regular';
  --ifm-heading-font-family: 'Poppins-Bold';
  --ifm-font-family-monospace: 'Poppins-Regular';
}
```

When i rebuild my docusaurus project i have other font generated (maybe default one) which is shown but not the Poppins one.

I have read [this](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/issues/3788) issue and try everything in there. Also check and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65333299/docusaurus-build-missing-fonts). But nothing helps.

Note: Interesting thing it is working when I import the font in custom.css file like

`@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap');`

But this doesn't help to me. I want to use it from a local folder.

Answer (score 1):

Add the import to `css/custom.css`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap');
```

I noticed in the browser how Google fonts are loaded using the Network tab (F12 -> Network-Refresh the page -> See the fonts below into the Name section) the extension of the fonts was in **'woff2'** format **not in 'ttf'** , then I downloaded the font with extension woff2 put it into my fonts folder then I added the code below:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins-Regular';
  src: url('../../static/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Regular.woff2') format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins-Bold';
  src: url('../../static/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Bold.woff2') format('woff2');
}

:root {
  --ifm-color-primary: #2e32ae;
  --ifm-font-family-base: 'Poppins-Regular';
  --ifm-heading-font-family: 'Poppins-Bold';
  --ifm-font-family-monospace: 'Poppins-Regular';
}
```

And it was fixed. Issue can be closed.